# Can I refer to an element in one datatemplate from another?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have solved this by moving properties in the view model so that there is no longer a "leaky" design where a "child" view wants to control the "parent" view.

I have view model objects that are displayed with datatemplates by Type.

The objects then have properties that are also displayed into datatemplates by Type. E.G.:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public ItemProperty1 { get; }
    public ItemProperty2 { get; }
    public bool LayoutBothItems { get; }
}

public class ItemProperty
{
    public double Value { get; }
    public bool IsValueInteresting { get; }
}

public class SpecializedItemProperty : ItemProperty {}
```

And then in XAML there are three datatemplates:

```
<!-- Enclosing DataTemplate inflates the DataGridCell itself: -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ItemViewModel}">
    <Grid x:Name="viewModelGrid">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ItemProperty, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>
    <!-- Here there are some Triggers that adjust the Grid based on <LayoutBothItems> -->
</DataTemplate>

<!-- DataTemplate inflates the Cell's properties: -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ItemProperty}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsValueInteresting, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
            <!--
                HERE:
            -->
            <Setter TargetName="viewModelGrid" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger?
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ItemProperty}">
    <!-- A different display for the specialized item ... -->
```

In the ItemProperty's inflated template I USED TO want to refer to the grid from the parent that inflated it ...

The point of this is: the "ItemViewModel" is an item in a DataGrid ItemsSource collection. Each particular item --- a Cell --- can have a certain specific "ItemProperty" types. The ItemViewModel's "viewModelGrid" is adjusted dynamically for a particular Cell layout, to arrange each ItemProperty. So then each of these Cells in the DataGrid inflates the ItemPropertys into some per-Cell layout.

So the ItemProperty data templates are designed to inflate for the specific type --- and they are like "sub-cells" in the DataGridCell ...

An ItemViewModel USED to want to set the background color based on some property, and in the visual Z-Order, the place I'd like to do that is in the enclosing "viewModelGrid" ... I have simply re-factored the code more sensibly so the sub-item does not "leak" up into the "parent". That obviously makes more sense.

Comment: You don't actually have a parent child relationship with your view models.  What you have is composition, or more generally, association.  Your child class does not derive from your parent class.

Comment: Yes: obviously, I know that ... The goal is to refer to the name "viewModelGrid" from the other datatemplate that has been inflated into that grid ...

Comment: Where is `viewModelGrid`?  I don't see that...

Comment: It's there in the first template: it contains the ContentPresenter that inflated the second template.

Comment: @rory.ap People often talk about parent/child viewmodels just as they do about parent/child controls or XML childNodes, not referring to inheritance at all.

Comment: `DataTemplate` to `DataTemplate` communication doesnt make sense, as a `DataTemplate` can be used for multiple controls. `DataTemplate` is like class, and you are asking for `Class` to `Class` communication. `Object` to `Object` makes sense.

Comment: Also try to post what u want to do, where those DTs would be used (DataGrid, ListBox, ContentControl etc) ?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have escaped my problem by re-factoring the view models ... It certainly simply makes more sense now --- I was trying to use a property on a "child" to control the background on the "parent" and I have simply re-factored that away. It makes much more sense. (I'm not absolutely sure that a scenario can't exist where a template that has inflated into another template might like to have some way to communicate with the enclosing template, but for now it seems obvious.) I'm moving forward with a design with separation between sub-elements and the enclosing cell.

Comment: @AnjumSKahn: Thanks for that thoughtful insight ... You're right. The goal here is to have something like "dynamically created controls" that inflate templates based on the specialized property object --- a single DataGrid Cell will contain one or more "sub controls" that each inflate a specific template. The Cell template actually dynamically changes it's Grid to lay out the children ... and each child then inflates a little "control" into the cell. The communication arrives at the visual level: I've re-factoired it away, but the "sub-cell" child used to want to interact with the Cell itself.